# marquee not scrolling to full text in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, marquee

Marquee is not scrolling to full text in chrome and IE but works perfectly in firefox

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2" scrolldelay="2" onmouseover="stop()"
                        onmouseout="start()" height="36" width="580"> <span runat="server" ID="lblNotiText" style="width:3000px ;">

Radio Bindaas  wishes all the listeners a very Happy Independence Day!!!  -- Director Sekhar Kammula launched the Radio Bindaas radio world wide.  -- Catch the exclusive interview with Sri Jayaprakash Narayan on this 66th Independence Day!!!  -- Mera Bharath Mahaan!!!!  -- hello  -- dsads  -- 
</span></marquee>
```

Comment: its working fine here(chrome)

Comment: Please post all your code as well.

Comment: @Ritabrata Gautam- My question is it is not scrolling to full text.

Comment: @Benedict Lewis- I have the above code inside a div of width=580px

Comment: Have you set a DOCTYPE?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

> Marquee is a non-standard HTML tag, first introduced in early versions
>   of Microsoft's Internet Explorer, and was compared to Netscape's blink
>   element. Marquee can be distracting. The human eye is attracted to
>   movement, and marquee text is constantly moving, as such W3C advises
>   against its use in HTML documents. IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome and
>   Safari web browsers support it for compatibility with legacy pages.

That aside, your code is working fine in Chrome (`28.0.1500.95`): http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/nHX6G/. I suggest you check your code using the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/). I also recommend that you look into replacing your code with [simpleScroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/), a jQuery plugin.